# Create Site Extension for Azure App Service and add to Gallery

Tags: azure, nuget-server, azure-app-service-envrmnt, nugetgallery

I Created a nuget package extension .nupkg with some content folder in it. I am trying that package to get added in the Site Extensions gallery of the Azure App Services. I created the Nuget package with Nuget Package explorer.

Initially with some link, I learnt that it needs to be uploaded in **www.siteextensions.net**. I tried it, my package got uploaded into that web site. But when I tried searching for my package in the Site Extensions in the scm site of the web app it dint get listed.

Then even i tried to upload the package in different name in **nuget.org**. But still that dint help out. It was not getting listed in the Azure App Service's Extensions.

How can i add my site extension to the Azure App service Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my reply from MSDN since we haven't heard back from you.

Site Extensions have been hosted on https://www.siteextensions.net/. Site Extensions have moved to https://www.nuget.org/, the same gallery that holds all NuGet packages.

More info on the transition here: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/87

When you use nuget.org, what happens when you upload it? Do you receive any error?